# validating 1 input of multiple inputs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, validation

I've got multiple input fields where they have the same class names. I need to check to make sure at least 1 of them isn't empty. So I've got,

```
$('form[name=expForm]').submit(function(){
 var msg = "";
 var found = false;
 $('.date-mask').each(function(){
  if($(this).val()){
   found = true;
  }
 });

 if (found != true)  {
```

msg += "Please provide at least 1 date before submitting.\n";
  return false;
 }
 var calcFnd = false;
 $('.calc').each(function(){
  if($(this).val()){
   calcFnd = true; 
  }
 });

if (calcFnd != true)  {
  msg += "Please provide at least 1 expense before submitting.\n";
  return false;
 }

if(msg != ""){
  alert(msg);
      return false;
     }

```
 if($('.ttlR27').val()==""){
  var net = $('.ttlR26').val();
  $('.ttlR28').val(net);
 }
 return false;

});

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(labels)#" index="r">
<tr>
 <td class="labels <cfif labels[r] EQ "Day of Week:">row1</cfif>"><cfif ArrayIsDefined(labels,r) AND labels[r] NEQ "Open1"><cfif labels[r] EQ "Open"><input type="text" id="descript#r#" name="descript#r#" class="description descript#r#" value="Enter text here" style="width:auto;" /><cfelse>#labels[r]#</cfif></cfif></td>   

 <cfloop from="1" to="7" index="i">
  <td id="Day#i#" class="row#r# col#i#">
   <cfif r EQ 1>#Left(DayOfWeekAsString(i),3)#<cfelse><cfif r EQ 2>
   <input type="text" class="date-mask" name="dates#i#" required="yes" message="Please provide at least 1 date before submitting.">
   <cfelse>
   <input type="text" 
   <cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage ##"> id="gasamount#i#" <cfelseif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage $">id="gasmoney#i#"</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Open">id="open#r#"</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals">id="dailytotals#i#"</cfif> class="all <cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage ##">gasamount <cfelse><cfif labels[r] NEQ "Daily Totals">C#i# </cfif></cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage $">gasmoney<cfelse>calc R#r#<cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals"> </cfif></cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals">ttlC#i#</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Less Advance(if applicable)"> less</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Net Due Employee"> net</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Open"> open</cfif>" 
    <cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals" OR labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage $" OR labels[r] EQ "Open1">readonly="readonly"</cfif>
    name="<cfif labels[r] NEQ "Personal Car: Mileage ##" AND labels[r] NEQ "Personal Car: Mileage $" AND labels[r] NEQ "Dates:" AND labels[r] NEQ "Open1" AND labels[r] NEQ "Daily Totals">R#r#.C#i#</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage ##">gasamt#i#</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals">celltotals#i#</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage $">gastot#i#</cfif>" /></cfif>
      </cfif>
  </td>
 </cfloop>

  <td class="totals<cfif r EQ 1>1</cfif>"><cfif r EQ 1>Total<cfelse><input type="text" <cfif labels[r] EQ "Less Advance(if applicable)">id="less"</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Net Due Employee">id="net"</cfif>id="totals" class="ttlR#r#" name="totals#r#" readonly="readonly" /></cfif></td>


</tr>
</cfloop>
```

The class names that are being used are: date-mask, for the top row of dates and calc, for the rest of the table.

I only need 1 input to not be empty to allow for a true submission.

Any ideas?

**Edit**
Here is the link to the live page. What I'm validating here are two different things, but essentially the same function. The first row, the dates. Also, the entire table. If not all, MOSTLY every input has one of the same classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@karim79's code should work.  Here, I wrote a proof of concept that it works:

The script:

```
function checkFields() {
    var found = false;
    $('.huh').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()){
            found = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (found == true)  {
        alert("at least one field has value");
    } else {
        alert("all fields are empty");
    }
}
```

The mark-up

```
<input type="text" class="huh" name="limit1" />
<input type="text" class="huh" name="limit2" />
<input type="text" class="huh" name="limit3" />
<input type="text" class="huh" name="limit4" />
<input type="text" class="huh" name="limit5" />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkFields();"/>
```

Try this code yourself on a clean html and you'll see that it actually works.

**Edit** for the added code: The code is not reaching the alert part because you are already returning false here: msg += "Please provide at least 1 date before submitting.\n"; return false; Don't return until you've shown the alert

Comment: Was working. I'll edit my code to give exactly what I've got.

Comment: I tried to not have to supply the original code because of the coldfusion involved. If you check the link, you'll see that I am using the code shown in your example. Does not return a message. Thus, not working. I put a return false at the end of the form submit, for debugging purposes.

Comment: The code is not reaching the `alert` part because you are already returning `false` here: `msg += "Please provide at least 1 date before submitting.\n"; return false;` Don't return until you've shown the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
var found = false;
$('.huh').each(function(){
   if($(this).val()){
      found = true;
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't even work for this. No errors, but no results. Check the link I've posted. The table is... pretty large, but it's consisted of .calc for everything except for the dates. The dates consist of .date-mask

Comment: @Michael, you know that you're supposed to use the `found` variable after the loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a validation flag you set in your code and submit if it's true.

```
var valid = false;
$('.huh').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
  if(value.length > 0){
    valid = true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

The first statement in the each will trim the whitespaces and then check for the length of the value.  If it's greater than 0 we have a value; set the valid flag to true and return false to stop the iterations.

Comment: Same result?  Care to elaborate?

Comment: I've double checked the code and tested it, I'm getting the correct result.  Can you explain why you downvoted?

Comment: I return 1 alert rather than a list of them all. I still return false for having a true statement. Does not work. That's what I mean.

Comment: I'm not at 100 reputation points.. I can't downvote.. Thanks though.

Comment: I guess there is a secret meaning to your question I'm missing! You want to make sure at least one isn't empty, that's what that code does. Using the 5 inputs you provided, valid is true if one or more of them have a value

Comment: Check the link I've posted. That should be able to give you more input. Thanks for trying to help btw.

Comment: I've looked at your link, can you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to accomplish?  Based on the other responses I think the question may be unclear.  Glad to help :)

Comment: It's still the same concept. The date fields need at least 1 out of the 7 fields not empty. The rest of the table has multiple classes, but they all have a universal connector class called, calc. I need at least 1 input box with the class name of calc and date-mask (date fields class) to have some sort of value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var valid = !!$.makeArray($('input.huh').map(function() { return this.value; })).join('');
```

Explanation:

Get all the inputs, map the array to just get the values, change the array to a JS array and join. If at least one has a value, the joined string will not be empty.

The !! just converts to a boolean (may or may not be necessary/desirable).

Comment: I really don't even want to attempt yours at the moment. It's a bit much for something like this. If all else fails, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... it's one line of code to get a boolean indicating whether you have any inputs with values.
This is just a more functional-oriented version of the loop in the accepted answer.